# In XML to PHP array not getting keys

Tags: php, xml

My server code is like:

```
<?php
    $xml_data='<Player uID="p59936">
        <Name>Wojciech Szczesny</Name>
        <Position>Goalkeeper</Position>
        <Stat Type="first_name">Wojciech</Stat>
        <Stat Type="last_name">Szczesny</Stat>
        <Stat Type="birth_date">1990-04-18</Stat>
        <Stat Type="birth_place">Warszawa</Stat>
        <Stat Type="first_nationality">Poland</Stat>
        <Stat Type="weight">84</Stat>
        <Stat Type="height">196</Stat>
        <Stat Type="jersey_num">1</Stat>
        <Stat Type="real_position">Goalkeeper</Stat>
        <Stat Type="real_position_side">Unknown</Stat>
        <Stat Type="join_date">2008-07-01</Stat>
        <Stat Type="country">Poland</Stat>
        </Player>';
    $xml = simplexml_load_string($xml_data); 
    $array = json_decode(json_encode($xml),true);
    echo "<pre>";print_r($array);exit;
?>
```

But now I am getting result like:

```
Array
(
    [@attributes] => Array
        (
            [uID] => p59936
        )

    [Name] => Wojciech Szczesny
    [Position] => Goalkeeper
    [Stat] => Array
        (
            [0] => Wojciech
            [1] => Szczesny
            [2] => 1990-04-18
            [3] => Warszawa
            [4] => Poland
            [5] => 84
            [6] => 196
            [7] => 1
            [8] => Goalkeeper
            [9] => Unknown
            [10] => 2008-07-01
            [11] => Poland
        )

)
```

So instead of key like : `first_name`, `last_name` I am getting keys like `0,1,2...`

So how to get key which specifies in XML?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, you actually don't need to json_encode/decode that. You can already use `SimpleXML` to traverse those values that you want.

That `print_r` is misleading, you'd think that after that dump, those `Type` attributes are missing but they are there. Here's an [eloquent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12437393/3859027) that discusses that issue.

But if you want to get those values you can do it this way (note that there are numerous of ways of getting this):

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($xml_data);
foreach($xml->Stat as $stat) {
    $type = (string) $stat->attributes()->Type;
    $node_value = (string) $stat;
    echo "$type: $node_value <br/>";
}
```

[Sample Output](http://codepad.viper-7.com/qAjTnP)

Comment: Thanks @Ghost its working, but now my question is whatever I have posted in question is just small part of whole xml. so how to convert whole xml data into php array with attribute ?

Comment: @Er.KT I don't see, how this can be done generally. I guess, you need to write a custom function to convert `$xml` into a PHP object.

Comment: It also works with [extending from SimpleXMLElement and overriding jsonSerialize and manipulate based on tagname (elaborated example)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16938322/367456).

Answer (score 1):

The reason for the *missing* attributes is [`json_encode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php#115655). When you look at it closely, you will see, that encoding swallows the attribute `Type`

```
$json = json_encode($xml);
print_r($json);
```

will show

> {"@attributes":{"uID":"p59936"},"Name":"Wojciech Szczesny","Position":"Goalkeeper","Stat":["Wojciech","Szczesny","1990-04-18","Warszawa","Poland","84","196","1","Goalkeeper","Unknown","2008-07-01","Poland"]}

See also this [comment](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php#115655) at the `json_encode` manual page.

But as @Ghost already pointed out, the attributes are still there in `$xml`, ready to be examined.

Answer (score 1):

This is either possible by changing the objects behavior on `json_serialize`, for example by looking for the tag-name and then change the returned data:

```
class MyJson extends SimpleXMLElement implements JsonSerializable
{

    public function jsonSerialize() {
        $name = $this->getName();

        if ($name !== 'Player') {
            return $this;
        }

        $data = [];
        foreach ($this as $name => $element) {
            if ($name === 'Stat') {
                $name = (string) $element['Type'];

            }
            $data[$name] = (string) $element;
        }

        return $data;
    }
}

$xml = simplexml_load_string($buffer, 'MyJson');
$array = json_decode(json_encode($xml), true);
print_r($array);
```

This produces the following output:

```
Array
(
    [Name] => Wojciech Szczesny
    [Position] => Goalkeeper
    [first_name] => Wojciech
    [last_name] => Szczesny
    [birth_date] => 1990-04-18
    [birth_place] => Warszawa
    [first_nationality] => Poland
    [weight] => 84
    [height] => 196
    [jersey_num] => 1
    [real_position] => Goalkeeper
    [real_position_side] => Unknown
    [join_date] => 2008-07-01
    [country] => Poland
)
```

Another alternative is to modify the document before you serialize it to JSON (and then back to an array).

The following example converts all `<Stat>` elements into elements named after the `Type` attribute containing the value of the original `<Stat>` element. The `<Stat>` elements are then removed:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($buffer);
foreach ($xml->xpath("//Player/Stat") as $stat) {
    $parent = $stat->xpath('..')[0];
    $parent->addChild((string) $stat["Type"])[0] = trim($stat);
    unset($stat[0]);
}

$array = json_decode(json_encode($xml), true);
print_r($array);
```

This example produces the following output:

```
Array
(
    [@attributes] => Array
        (
            [uID] => p59936
        )

    [Name] => Wojciech Szczesny
    [Position] => Goalkeeper
    [first_name] => Wojciech
    [last_name] => Szczesny
    [birth_date] => 1990-04-18
    [birth_place] => Warszawa
    [first_nationality] => Poland
    [weight] => 84
    [height] => 196
    [jersey_num] => 1
    [real_position] => Goalkeeper
    [real_position_side] => Unknown
    [join_date] => 2008-07-01
    [country] => Poland
)
```

These are just two examples. Both could create the same output, it's just showing two different places where you can place the logic to convert the document.

Related Resources:

- [PHP convert XML to JSON group when there is one child](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16935560/367456)
- [Getting an array from object using SimpleXMLElement](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13999398/367456)